# react-typeahead: Get the id of the element selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using [react-typeahead](https://github.com/fmoo/react-typeahead), I'm trying to store and fetch the id of the element when an option is selected or the form is submitted

So far I have this:

```
data = [{ id: 1, name: "something", id: 2, name: "else"}];
```

I use a map like this to get only the names because Typeahead options expect an array of strings as default, so we lose the id here.

```
map(function (item) {return item.name;})

<Typeahead options={categories} placeholder="Categories" />
```

My question is how can I preserve and get the id of the category when the form is submitted or the option is selected.

This would be the form:

```
<form method="get" action="/" className="form-inline" >
  <Typeahead options={categories} onOptionSelected={this._handleOnOptionSelected} placeholder={text} maxVisible={5} />
  <Link to="/search" onClick={this._handleOnClick} className="btn btn-wa-primary">Search</Link>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`onOptionSelected`](https://github.com/fmoo/react-typeahead/blob/master/src/typeahead/index.js#L71) callback for react-typeahead to obtain the selected option and use it to find the id:

```
/* somewhere in your top component */

handleOptionSelected: function(option) {
  // find the id from the data array
  var id = data.find(function(d) { 
    return d.name === option;
  }); 
  // ... now you have the id
},

/* somewhere in the render() method of your top component */
<Typeahead options={categories} 
           placeholder="Categories"
           onOptionSelected={this.handleOptionSelected} />
```

Since you aren't showing a form anywhere, I cannot address the "on form submit".

---

Note: You can optimize this by using a map to lookup ids instead of an array. Something like:

```
var map = {
  "something": 1,
  "else": 2
};
```

Where, `id` would be `map[option]`.

Comment: Thanks, so far your answer helped me, I was able to get the id of the selected element, I wasn't aware of onOptionSelected had the text as the first parameter, I've added the form to the question.

Comment: I used this.setState to preserve the state of the item selected, and that should be it. thanks for your answer.